# How to edit user profile with felogin from frontend in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I need to edit the website user data  and set new password from frontend. How is this possible by TYPO3 `felogin` extension? Please help me.

Comment: I think with the felogin ext. isn't it possible. Had you taken a look into the Repository for an extension? A good choice is femanager for example.

Alternatively the felogin ext supports "forgot password" i think:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/Configuration/Index.html#showforgotpasswordlink

Comment: @HR123 thank you for your quick response.I this femanager will meet my requirement

Comment: @HR123 change your comment to an answer and then Aswathy S can vote your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the felogin ext. isn't it possible. Had you taken a look into the Repository for an extension? A good choice is femanager for example. Alternatively the felogin ext supports "forgot password" i think:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/Configuration/Index.html#showforgotpasswordlink